# Performing navigation in mvvm with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Iam using MVVM with RxSwift i have tried Coordinator  and RxFlow to navigate between viewcontroller.
Is there any simply approach to segue between viewcontroller with RxSwift

```
  viewModel.users.subscribe {
                            model in


                            self.walkthrough = WalkthroughModel(country: (model.element?.country)!, countryCode: (model.element?.countryCode)!,PhoneNumber:"")

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Walkthrough_phone", sender: self)
                            }
                        }.dispose()
```

these the normal approach iam doing right now  but  is there any way to bind segu to the button

Comment: provide us some code?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban edited

Comment: what exactly you trying to achieve? bind action to button?

Comment: Performing segue inside viewmodel and binding that to rx.tap in view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think segue should be perform in view controller because it is UI action, and it has nothing to do with view model. You should hold reference to viewModel inside viewController class, so you can easy access it properties while do tap on button in view controller class.

Performing tap to button with RxSwift look like that:

```
btn.rx.tap
  .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in 
     // Do segue
  })
  .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Comment: After series of operations segue should happen

Comment: btn.rx.tap
  .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
  .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in 
     // Do segue
  })
  .addDisposableTo(self.bag)

Comment: the code in the answer is way out of MVVM. view model is responsible for proceeding the tap. the tap might trigger multiple operations, not only segue.

Comment: @iWheelBuy if you have better solution, answer for this question with correctly worked code snippet.

Comment: @iWheelBuy i realise that you right and want to see correct solution and answer, so if you provide one it will be better then leave my "incorrect" answer.

Answer (score 3):

RxFlow may become the answer.

> RxFlow is a navigation framework for iOS applications based on a Reactive Flow Coordinator pattern

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxFlow